# Generate Oracle reports xml using java

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jasper-reports

I have a client who wants to maintain their Oracle report xml for printing their Statements but I am using java and jasper reports to generate the PDF reports. The xml goes to a third party for printing. Is there a way by any means of invoking or development I can generate the same oracle report xml. I have googled to no avail. This is the Oracle report xml formating:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 6.0.8.18.0 -->
<CDSTXN05>
  <LIST_G_CLIENT_PREFIX>
    <G_CLIENT_PREFIX>
      <CLIENT_PREFIX>0000xxxxxxxxx0</CLIENT_PREFIX>
      <CLIENT_SUFFIX>LI</CLIENT_SUFFIX>
      <JOINT_AC_NO>0</JOINT_AC_NO>
      <LIST_G_MEMBER_CODE>
        <G_MEMBER_CODE>
          <BROKER>B12-B</BROKER>
          <MNAME>CUSTOMER NAME</MNAME>
          <MADD1>CUSTOMER ADDRESS</MADD1>
          <MADD2>CITY</MADD2>
          <MADD3>FINANCE HOUSE</MADD3>
          <MTOWN></MTOWN>
          <MCOUNTY></MCOUNTY>
          <MSTATE></MSTATE>
          <MPOSTCODE></MPOSTCODE>
          <MCOUNTRY>COUNTRY</MCOUNTRY>
          <MEMBER_CODE>B1</MEMBER_CODE>
          <MEMBER_TYPE>B</MEMBER_TYPE>
          <M_COUNTRY_CODE>CD</M_COUNTRY_CODE>
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Any ideas, example or links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

try this :

[Example Line](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/examples/xslt_samples.zip)

[Writing out a DOM object for xml eg](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html)

[Oracle XML Schema Details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96621/adx06scj.htm#1005238)

[Oracle Developer's XML kit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23582/adx_overview.htm)

[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/examples/xslt_samples.zip):[image]

Comment: A bit more explanation or steps to achieve the requirement would be much appreciated!

Comment: you wanted to genrate reports in the form of this xml you mentioned ?

Comment: I didn't mention, OP mentioned. I just suggested you to elaborate a bit. It might even help you as it helps others in the community :-)

Comment: i have updated a link on  Oracle XML Schema Details please check.it has complete details you will get from there.

Comment: As an expectation, OP would have looked at fine manuals. The point is, link only answers aren't appreciated here in SO. A well desribed answer is pretty much appreciated as well as upvoted. That's my whole point.